# Invoke Methods dynamically using Method.invoke() with array that has the Parameters

Tags: kotlin

I have below code which was supposed to call 2 methods `concatenation(1, 2, mapOf("S" to "M"))` and `subtraction(5, 3)`:

```
  private fun concatenation(a: Int, b: Int, c: Map<String, String>): String {
    return a.plus(b).toString().plus(c.values.toString())
  }

  private fun subtraction(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
    return a - b
  }

  @Test
  fun test() {
    val methods = listOf(
      ::concatenation,
      ::subtraction
    )
    val arguments = listOf(
      arrayOf(1, 2, mapOf("S" to "M")),
      arrayOf(5, 3)
    )
    val result = methods.zip(arguments).map { (method, args) ->
      {
        if (method.parameters.size == args.size) {
          method.invoke(*args) //this line does not work
        } else {
          println("The number of arguments does not match the number of parameters in the target method")
        }
      }
    }
    println(result)
  }
```

But I have error in method.invoke() because each method has different number of arguments.

How do I do this in Kotlin in an elegant manner?

Comment: please correct me, if I wrong, but an array is only matched with `*`-Operator to a `varargs` parameter.

Comment: As @JohannKexel just wrote, you need _method.invoke(args[0], args[1])_ or change _addition_ and _subtraction_ to "vararg" parameters.

Comment: I was looking for a generic solution. What if the `addition` method requires 3 arguments of different datatype each (like String, Integer, Map<String, String> etc). vararg can only be of 1 datatype but I would need multiple varargs

Answer (score 0):

The below code works if I change `method.invoke()` to `method.call()`. And remove private keyword for function or use the `method.isAccessible = true`.

```
  fun concatenation(a: Int, b: Int, c: Map<String, String>): String {
    return a.plus(b).toString().plus(c.values.joinToString())
  }

  fun subtraction(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
    return a - b
  }

  @Test
  fun test() {
    val methods = listOf(
      ::concatenation,
      ::subtraction
    )
    val arguments = listOf(
      arrayOf(1, 2, mapOf("S" to "M")),
      arrayOf(5, 3)
    )
    val result = methods.zip(arguments).map { (method, args) ->
      if (method.parameters.size == args.size ||
         (method.parameters.size - 1 <= args.size && method.parameters.last().isVararg)
      ) {
        //method.isAccessible = true
        method.call(*args)
      } else {
        println("The number of arguments does not match the number of parameters in the target method")
      }
    }
    println(result)
  }
```

Comment: But there is no type checking at compile time in this solution so unless there is a workaround to do the type checking at compile time, I would avoid this solution approach